# How to save WebView state when external keyboard connected?

Tags: android, webview

When I connect external keyboard using OTG(A4TECH GX-110), my Activity is creating from scratch. This is causing recreating `WebView` .

This is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="uz.cp.oxmini.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wvOx" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried to save `WebView` state, then `onCreate()` method to restore saved state.

```
private WebView mWebview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mWebview = new WebView(this);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        mWebview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
    else {
        mWebview.loadUrl("http://joerichard.net");
        setContentView(mWebview);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    mWebview.saveState(outState);
}
```

But result is screen with grey background

[image]

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: where is your xml file

Comment: @RohanPawar, I do not know how this can help, anyways added, you can find it in edited question

Answer (score 0):

I have added onRestoreInstanceState and modified onSaveInstance method little bit. And now I am restoring webview state in onRestoreInstanceState. Moreover I have changed check savedInstanceState is null or not:

```
        private WebView mWebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mWebview = new WebView(this);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            mWebview.loadUrl("http://joerichard.net");
        }

setContentView(mWebview);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mWebview.saveState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mWebview.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
    }
```